# Is it always possible to decompose the metric tensor of a spacetime using an arbitrary well-defined vector field ( or rather flow)?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In his book, *A relativist's toolkit*, in the section where Poisson is talking about the expansion and sheer vectors, he uses *deviation vectors* to decompose the metric into two parts. But to me, it looks so arbitrary, and I wonder where and how I can utilize such trickery in different areas of GR.

I'm not a smart person, so my questions come from a place of *not understanding* and I'd be more than glad if you could show me how to think about such matters.

I tried to look around (the net) for a clue but couldn't find any. Thanks a bunch

Comment: You can use the NP formalism to express a metric in terms of complex orthonormal null vectors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newman%E2%80%93Penrose_formalism   The 3+1 formalism can be used to decompose a metric wrt a given time-like vector field

Comment: Hi @KP99 thanks for your comment. I'm a bit familiar with the spacetime decomposition methods you mentioned. But they all have a specific vantage point or a key assumption in their definition and use. However, for what Poisson does, having a time-like congruence of geodesics sounds enough. How arbitrarily can I choose my vector filed to work for metric decomposition?